# Confining User Inputed Numbers Between 1 and 30

Tags: java

I am writing a program that asks for 5 user inputed numbers; however, I need to keep those numbers confined between 1 and 30. I am having trouble writing the while loop for this part of the program.

Here is my code:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

         int numberCounter = 0; // Set scanner to 0
         // Intialize numbers 1-5
         int number1; 
         int number2;
         int number3;
         int number4;
         int number5;
         String asterisk = "*"; // Holds the string value "*"

 int number = 0;
             while (number < 1 || number > 30){
                 System.out.print("Enter the first number (between 1-30): ");
                 number = keyin.nextInt();
             }

         System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: ");// Calls for user input
         number1 = input.nextInt();// Stores user input for number 1

         System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: ");// Calls for user input
         number2 = input.nextInt();// Stores user input for number 2

         System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: ");// Calls for user input
         number3 = input.nextInt();// Stores user input for number 3

         System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: ");// Calls for user input
         number4 = input.nextInt();// Stores user input for number 4

         System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: ");// Calls for user input
         number5 = input.nextInt();// Stores user input for number 5

         System.out.printf("%d ", number1);
         for (int i = 1; i <= number1; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();

         System.out.printf("%d ", number2);
         for (int i = 1; i <= number2; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();

         System.out.printf("%d ", number3);
         for (int i = 1; i <= number3; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();

         System.out.printf("%d ", number4);
         for (int i = 1; i <= number4; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();

         System.out.printf("%d ", number5);
         for (int i = 1; i <= number5; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();

     }

 }
```

Can anyone help steer my in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: function call...........

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid redundant code by keeping the nextInt() inside while loop and use a counter to track the desired number of inputs you want to read. And exit the loop when all the valid numbers are read.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    byte maxNum = 31;
    byte minNum = 1;

    int[] numbers = new int[5];

    int number = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i<5) {

        System.out.print("Enter number("+(i+1)+") between "+minNum + " and "+maxNum+ " : ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        if(number >=minNum && number <= maxNum){
            numbers[i] = number;
            i++;
        }else{
            System.out.println("--------Invalid Number :"+number+ " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Entered Numbers :");

    for(int n : numbers){
        System.out.print(n + ",");
    }
```

Note : Code may fail, for char and out of range of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Math.max(new int[]{number1,number2,number3,number4,number5}) <= 30 && Math.min(new int[]{number1,number2,number3,number4,number5}) >= 1){
    ...WITHIN YOUR RANGE...
}else{

}
```

What this does is check if the max of the set is less than or equal to 30, and the min of the set is more than or equal to 1, and then executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose of this program is to ask user to input 5 numbers between 1 and 30, I think you should write 'while' loop for each of the input task to be sure that each number is within the range and to ask user again if it's not.